# Possible to get list item (<li>) label with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, dom

If I've got a `ul` with 3 items in it and the `list-style-type` is set to `lower-alpha`, I end up with this

> a. Item 1
>
> b. Item 2
>
> c. Item 3

With jQuery, I can easily get the value of any item you click - "Item 1" if I click the first. But can I get the list item label? In this case *a*?

Comment: on a side note, if you're list has an order it should really be `<ol>`

Comment: I'm using an OL, so I would get numbers, there has to be a way to get that through JavaScript. Not necessary I know, but it would be slick.

Comment: @bo1 If the browser doesn't have an API, it should be easy to determine the index of a current element to its parent, which would be the list number.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if the DOM API exposes that, but you could do...

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var label = String.fromCharCode(97 + $(this).index());
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmxa44qo/)

...if you had **under 26** elements. If you have more, you would need to use a more complicated algorithm, typically known as the *Excel Row to Column* algorithm.

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var index = $(this).index() + 1;
  var label = '';
  var mod;

  while (index) {
    mod = (index - 1) % 26;
    label = String.fromCharCode(97 + mod) + label;
    index = Math.floor((index - mod) / 26);
  }
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z3wd2se2/)