# How to get the index of list Items on click of li using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

Is there a way through which I can get the index of list Items on click of `li` element using JavaScript/jQuery?

```
<ul>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800210/possible-to-get-list-item-li-label-with-javascript/2800220?stw=2#2800220 (for alphabetic indexes)

Answer (score 17):

```
$('ul li').click(function(){ alert($(this).index()); });
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the onClick event to call the function getIndex (no jQuery needed, just vanilla javascript):

```
onClick = "getIndex(this);"

function getIndex(node) {
  var childs = node.parentNode.childNodes;
  for (i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
    if (node == childs[i]) break;
  }
  return i;
}
```

Index will start beginning with 0! To let it start with 1 : **`return i+1`**